# Flutter - How to parse nested JSON structures with lists in flutter?

Tags: android, json, flutter

Here is my JSON

```
{
  "type-1":[
    {
      "name": "type-1-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "type-1-2"
    }
  ],
  "type-2": [
    {
      "name": "type-2-1"
    },
    {
      "name": "type-2-2"
    },
    {
      "name": "type-2-3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to parse this JSON so for that I have written my model like this

```
class Places {
  final List<PlaceName> names;
  Places({this.names});

  factory Places.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    var list = parsedJson['name'] as List;
    List<PlaceName> placeList = list.map((i) => PlaceName.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return Places(
        names: placeList
    );
  }
}


class PlaceName {
  final String name;
  PlaceName({this.name});
  factory PlaceName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson){
    return PlaceName(
        name : parsedJson['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

and lastly, I have written my function in widget tree like this

```
Future<String> _loadAllPlaces() async {
    return await rootBundle.loadString('assets/location.json');
  }

  Future loadPlaces() async {
    String jsonString = await _loadAllPlaces();
    final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
    PlaceName place = new PlaceName.fromJson(jsonResponse);
    print(place);
    print(place.name);
    return place;
  }
```

So when I call `loadPlaces()` in FutureBuilder its returning null. I tried debugging it but no luck. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What debugging have you tried? Please share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `Places.fromJson` method at the line `var list = parsedJson['name']` you are trying to access the list inside the objects before referencing the object itself. Instead you should pass the name of the one of the objects like `type-1` by example, in this way `var list = parsedJson['type-1'] as List;`.

But this would return just the first object's list. To get all the objects and the list of names of each one, you need iterate over the json objects , which in that example are `type-1` and `type-2`, and then iterate over its lists. You can check the iteration in `AllPlaces.fromJson`. So you need to do some changes in your code to get all the objects from the json. You can try something like the code bellow, that you can test at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/)

```
import 'dart:convert';

String jsonString = '{"type-1":[{"name": "type-1-1"},{"name": "type-1-2"}],"type-2": [{"name": "type-2-1"},{"name": "type-2-2"},{"name": "type-2-3"}]}';


class AllPlaces {
  List<PlaceName> placeNames;

  AllPlaces({this.placeNames});

  AllPlaces.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    placeNames = new List<PlaceName>();
    //Iterates over the json objects.
     json.forEach((type, list) {
      //Iterates over the list of each object.
      json[type].forEach((list) {
        //Creates an instance of PlaceName and adds to the placeNames list.
        placeNames.add(new PlaceName.fromJson(list));
      });
    });
  }
}

class PlaceName {
  String name;

  PlaceName({this.name});

  PlaceName.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
  }

}

Future loadPlaces() async {
   //String jsonString = await _loadAllPlaces();
   final jsonResponse = json.decode(jsonString);
   AllPlaces allPlaces = new AllPlaces.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  
   //Print the names of each object in the console
   allPlaces.placeNames.forEach((place) => print(place.name));
   
   return allPlaces;
}


void main() {
  loadPlaces();
}
```

Comment: Please add a description that clarifies the differences between this and the OP's code.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore, I edited the answer. Check if it's looks better.